# How to focus textfield after executing the textfield's callout in Adempiere

Tags: textfield, callout, adempiere

I have problem about callout in Adempiere. I have one callout in textfield, I want that after executing this callout, the cursor will focus on other textfield as we want
Please help me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you please briefly elaborate what was the problem?
Do you need to call another callout ?

Field focus change purpose we need to modify the core classes of Framework.